# How do I pass the updated page content to another function?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have some code for selenium-webdriver, like this:

```
 base_url = 'http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/spotquery'
 driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 driver.get(base_url)
```

And after entering the login and password, the page will be updated after this code:

```
btn_elem_upd = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-submit').click()
```

Next need to transfer the updated page to another function, like this:

```
url = "Here need transfer the new updated page"
res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.text)
```

How can this be done? What are the options?
UPDATE, if I write like this, the code works:

```
new_source = 'http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/spots'
res = requests.get(new_source)

doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.text)

cols = []

cols.append(doc.xpath('//table/tr[1]/node()/text()')[0])
for item in doc.xpath('//table/tr/th'):
    typ = str(type(item.getnext()))
    if not 'NoneType' in typ:
        cols.append(item.getnext().text)

inf = []
for item in doc.xpath('//table//tr//td'):
    inf.append(item.text.replace('\\xa02', '').strip()) 

rows = [inf[x:x+len(cols)] for x in range(0, len(inf), len(cols))]

with open("output.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(cols)
    for l in rows:
        writer.writerow(l)
```

If I rewrite:

```
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
cols = []
cols.append(doc.xpath('//table/tr[1]/node()/text()')[0])
```

the code does not work with an error:

```
cols.append(doc.xpath('//table/tr[1]/node()/text()')[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Is it that you want `URL` after login?

Comment: @TekNath yes, but before login url = http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/spotquery , and after login url = http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/spotquery. But page content is different.

Comment: After click on `submit` button if you use `driver.page_source` you will get the HTML.This is what you are after?

Comment: @KunduK yes, I try this way. But if I write url = driver.page_source , the next line throws an error -  res = requests.get(url). 
I need to rewrite the code so that the next construct works:                                 res = requests.get(url)
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(res.text)

Comment: Can you post your html after login and what value you are after?

Comment: Try this `doc = lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)` Instead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204061/discussion-between-outlaw-and-kunduk).

Comment: @Jack Fleeting can you help in this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion you can use **pandas** library to read table information and load into **csv** file.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://wsprnet.org/drupal/wsprnet/spotquery")
login = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-name')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-pass')
btn_elem_log = driver.find_element_by_id('edit-submit--2')
login.send_keys('username')
password.send_keys('password')
btn_elem_log.click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"edit-call"))).send_keys("searchval")
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"edit-excludespecial"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"edit-submit"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME,"table")))
page=driver.page_source
df=pd.read_html(page)
df[0].to_csv("csvfile.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a redirect to that new page using JavaScript run within your selenium code. Selenium supports this. So you can try

```
driver.execute_script(f"window.location.replace('{new_url}');")
```

That should send your web-driver to the new URL

You might want to open this is a new tab if you are going to run it in a different function, just in case, to open in new tab you can use this:

```
driver.execute_script(f"window.open('{new_url}');")
```

This will open the URL in a new tab instead of in the currently active tags, although this will also mean you will have to switch between tabs to access the different web pages and you may want to close tabs after using them or it can get messy.

Comment: No, it's no working. Url is the same, content is changing